# How to implement PHP / jQuery Online Document viewer?

Tags: php, jquery, api, yii, documentviewer

My Application is developed in PHP Yii Framework.
My Application has a private network module where members of the network can upload files for sharing among them. Right now I'm using Amazon S3 to save the files.
Is there any way I can provide an option to generate Preview for these files so that the user can view them online before downloading the file.

Here is what I've come across in my Research:

```
Group Docs:
http://groupdocs.com/pricing/api-pricing. This is paid version and I'm not sure about the privacy of my documents. 

Zoho Docs
https://www.zoho.com/docs/
I'm not sure if they have an API to support the document viewing feature.

Google Drive(Formerly Google Docs)
https://developers.google.com/drive/
I'm not sure if I can only open the documents using Google Drive and not save to them on google drive.
```

These files are extremely private and security is of very high concern in my application.

If any one has any suggestions / thoughts for this scenario, please share them with me.

Thanks

Comment: If you email the file to the user, at least in gmail they can preview almost any file

Comment: Thanks mplungjan. But my requirement is to preview the document online before downloading the files / Sending them by Email. And not everyone uses gmail right.

Comment: You won't find free version. Do it yourself or pay.

Comment: http://docs.filerun.com/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: @Peter Szymkowski I'm willing to pay if an appropriate service is available.

Comment: @BhargavBonu i saw some paid API somewhere but I can't find it :(

Comment: @Bhargav Did you find any solution to it?
I am also looking for such a solution, TO show all kinds of documents on my browser use can simply view documents.

Comment: @shivanikoko didn't find any libraries at that time. Here is what I found out in my recent research. https://viewerjs.org/ Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Please try this [link](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-document-viewer/1732515) it will help you

`Document Viewer` is a `jQuery plugin` that allows you to view several file formats directly in a web page. The file formats that `Document Viewer` supports are:

- **PDF** Files
- **Text** Files
- **Code** – bsh, c, cc, cpp, cs, csh, css, cyc, cv, htm, html, java, js, m, mxml, perl, php, pl, pm, py, rb, sh, xhtml, xml, xsl, sql, vb
- Images – png, jpg, jpeg, gif
- **Audio** – mp3, m4a, oga, webma, fla
- **Video** – m4v, ogv, ogg, webmv, flv,mpg, mpeg, mov, divx, avi

Comment: It supports basic file formats like PDF and other media files. But I'm also looking for support to these document files: .doc, .xls etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah can be done i am using it .

2 choices for multiple file types :

1. Use Google doc viewer 5 simple fast some restrictions and free )
2. Use Pdf.js which is very good at displaying pdf dynamically without making every page an image like Google viewer do ! , and you can search and select text and others amazing stuff , this is used on Firefox .

OR try paid services they have even a 3D view for document ;)